# Кавычки в словосочетании "умный город"

Tags: орфография, пунктуация, фразеология

Нужно ли прилагательное *умный* в данном случае брать в кавычки?

В англоязычной литературе никаких кавычек при этом словосочетании нет. Можно ли употреблять *умный город* без кавычек?

Comment: Какого, какого языка?

Answer (score 2):

**Всё сочетание пишется в кавычках —** "умный город" (это пока еще условное название).

[Умный город: Эффективное управление развитием | geektimes.ru](https://geektimes.ru/company/gsgroup/blog/265366/)

> *Но все-таки, что значит «умный город»? Однако некоторые проекты «умных городов» ушли не в том направлении.*

И т.д.

Например, у Розенталя:

> Заключаются в кавычки слова, употребленные в условном значении
>   (применительно к ситуации или контексту), например: В последние годы
>   перед лицом надвигающейся экологической катастрофы движение
>   **«зеленых»** приобретает широкий размах.

Comment: Хм. А в документе по ссылке http://www.unece.org/fileadmin/DAM/hlm/documents/2015/ECE_HBP_2015_4.ru.pdf применяются кавычки только к "умный". И почему тогда англоязычные вообще их не применяют?

Comment: Скорее всего,  термин еще неустоявшийся, отсюда вариативность записей "умный город", "умный дом". Например, пишут: технология "Умный дом", система "умный дом" . Иногда в одном тексте встречается запись   с кавычками и без них, например: «Умные» города. Перспективы развития в России (название). Далее в тексте: Наиболее удачным примером умного города, построенного с нуля, считается южнокорейский Сонгдо. А вот уже запись без условных кавычек: 29-30 ноября 2016 года пройдет V международный форум «Умный город будущего».

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы дать ответ, необходимо иметь контекст. 
Мне непонятно, что тут вообще "умный" может значить.

Что касается ссылки от Sibylla, то по первому впечатлению - кавычек тут не надо, поскольку "условность" весьма слабая. Ср. умная книга, умное решение. Что тут условного?
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x

А если уж заключать, то вместе с городом.

Comment: Вы правильно всё говорите. только "умный город" - в общем-то уже состоявшееся сочетание. Еще не общеизвестное, но достаточно однозначное. Не надо гадать о смысле.